# Enumerate the unordered pairs (2-combinations) of a set

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, combinations, combinatorics

I'd like to iterate through an ArrayList representing a set of Persons and compare the content of each Person with each other Person. The content are full of Hasmaps in this form. I need to compare the Value of the matching Key (Key is unique) and get the difference of the Integer. This should iterate through all the Hashmaps and for all the Persons in the Arraylist. But I shouldn't compare p.e. Person A with Person C and then Person C again with Person A.

How can I code it?
I'm struggling for the last 3 hours.

```
public Integer comparison(){
   ArrayList<HashMap> personList = new ArrayList<>();

   for(int i = 0; i < personList.size(); i++){
      HashMap<String, Integer> persons = new HashMap<>();

      for(int j = i+1; j<persons.size(); j++){
         // sum up the differences
      }
      difference+=difference;
   }
   return difference;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. But why are you using "new HashMap<>()" don't you want the list entry?

Comment: you need to sort the array and compare each entry with the rest after the current entry .

Comment: could you give an example of input and expected output?

Comment: @PatrickParker: I have like a personA from personList with the HashMaps("test1", 1), ("test2", 4)("test3", 6), ("test4", 3), personB with ("test1", 3), ("test2", 2)("test3", 1), ("test4", 5), and a personC with ("test1", 4), ("test2", 1)("test3", 5), ("test4", 2),

Output should be like: personA compared with personB = 2 + 2 + 5 + 2 = 11
personA compared with personC = 3 + 3+ 1 + 1 = 8
personB compared with personC= 1 + 1 + 4 + 3 = 9

I took the Value and took the difference out of them and summed it up.

Comment: Ok... then what should be the output for that example?

Comment: @PatrickParker: Sry, I just edited my Comment.

Comment: @PatrickParker Output should be like: personA compared with personB = 2 + 2 + 5 + 2 = **11** personA compared with personC = 3 + 3+ 1 + 1 = **8** personB compared with personC= 1 + 1 + 4 + 3 = **9** I took the Value and took the difference out of them and summed it up.

Answer (score 1):

This topic in mathematics uses what are called [Combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) wherein you need to find the set of all **k-combinations of a set** (persons A, B, and C). In this case it is simple to get all the combinations, because you know it is always only required to choose two elements; that is, *k=2*. See my outer loop and inner loop below for an easy way of achieving this:

```
    for(int a=0; a < personList.size()-1 /* stop before last */; a++) {
        for(int b=a+1 /* start after first */; b < personList.size(); b++) {
            int sumDiff = 0;
            System.out.print("person"+(char)('A'+a)+" compared with person"+(char)('A'+b)+" = ");
            Set<String> keys = personList.get(a).keySet();
            keys.retainAll(personList.get(b).keySet()); // keys in both only
            for(String key : keys) {
                sumDiff += Math.abs(personList.get(a).get(key)-personList.get(b).get(key));                 
            }
            System.out.println(sumDiff);
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

> personA compared with personB = 11
>
> personA compared with personC = 8
>
> personB compared with personC = 9

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is very unclear as to what you want to do. I am assuming that you have been given the personList and you pass it to the function you are writing. If you want the result as a list of individual comments you need to add them to a list and return a List instead of an Integer.

The following code for your example should return a List which contains the values {11,8,9}. If you want the sum of these values like 11+8+9 then instead of adding each difference to a list add it to a variable initialized to 0 and declared outside the 1st for loop.

```js
public List<Integer> comparison(ArrayList<HashMap> personList){
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //int res = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < personList.size(); i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j< personList.size(); j++){
            int difference = 0
            for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : personList.get(i).entrySet()){
                String key = entry.getKey();
                int val = entry.getValue();
                difference += Math.abs(personList.get(j).get(key) - val);
            }
        }
        //res += difference
        result.add(difference);
   }
   //return res;
   return result;
}
```